# How to read long text file and print a part from text file

Tags: python, file-handling

I want to read a long text file after read, print a special id from the text file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQnXO.png)

```
read and get MY_ID from sample.txt file
```

code which try-

```py
def read_long_text_file():

    with open("path\sample.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            for part in line.split():
                if "MY_ID=" in part:
                    print(part)
            print line

read_long_text_file()
```

basically from this code output is that

MY_ID=120562

my desire is that only id will print on terminal like as
120562

does anybody solve my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
print(part.split("=")[1])
```

instead of:

```
print(part)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for that

```py
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if match := re.search(r'(?<=MY_ID=)\d+', line):
            id = int(match.group(0))
            print(id) # 123456789
```

Assuming your text file looks like this:

```
# file.txt
abcdef
409283120983

MY_ID=123456789

9298301923
```